# I need to figure out the length of a crystal to move a light beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, refraction, geometric-optics

I need to figure out the length of a crystal to move a light beam shining through it.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The height is known, and so is the refractive index of the crystal and its length. What I can't figure out is the angle $\alpha$.

I came to a set of equation but even after using Mathematica, I can't get an answer. The equations are as follows:
$$\sin(\alpha)=n\sin(\delta)$$
$$s=\frac{L_q}{\cos(\delta)}$$
$$\Delta x=s\sin(\alpha - \delta),$$
where $n$ is the refractive index, $\delta, \alpha$ are as shown in the picture, $L_q$ is the length of the crystal, and $s$ is the distance the beam has traveled in the crystal.

Comment: The equations seem to be correct;  but I wouldn't expect the resulting solution for $\alpha$ to be a "nice" equation, and it may be that it doesn't have a closed-form solution at all (a so-called *transcendental equation*).  If you have specific numerical values in mind, `FindRoot` in Mathematica is probably your best bet (rather than trying to use `Solve`.)  If you need help implementing that, rephrase your question and ask it on [Mathematica.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert okay thank you, using ```FindRoot```  it worked.